# Is it possible to use RedisJson and RedisSearch to filter objects by the length of array property?

Tags: redis, redisearch, redisjson

If I have multiple keys of JSON type in Redis DB that have the following form (Each key have different amount of users)

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Alice",
            "age": 15
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

By using RedisJson and RedisSearch, How can I filter all the objects that their `users.length` `>` or `<` or `=` to X ? (for example, get all the objects with `users.length > 10`)

Answer (score 2):

currently `length` is not supported as JSONPath expression. As a workaround, you can use `JSON.ARRLEN`https://redis.io/commands/json.arrlen/ command and execute the logic on the application/client side.

Comment: I've ended up adding logic on the object insertion and added an additional field of the array length.

Comment: you can also use redisGears to do that on the server side, if you really want to